# Useless instructions generated by GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I compile this simple C code with GCC:

```
int foo(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a += 1;
    *b += 1;
    *a += 1;
}

int foo2(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a += 1;
    *b += 1;
    *a += 1;
}
```

and it produces the following assembly code:

```
foo:
    add     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
    add     DWORD PTR [rsi], 1
    add     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
    ret
foo2:
    add     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
    xor     eax, eax
    add     DWORD PTR [rsi], 1
    add     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
    ret
```

see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rqhr6fxqM)

What is the point of this `xor` instruction?
In C++, GCC does not insert it and clang never does.

Comment: I think this is because your `foo2` doesn't properly return anything. This should be a warning.

Comment: @tadman No ____

Comment: I'd suspect it's the compiler clearing out the return value register as you do not have a `return` here even though *you promised to `return` an `int`*. If I make these functions `void` the `xor` operation goes away.

Comment: @tadman I understand what the xor does, but I don't understand why is it here.
Yes the lack of return is a warning and the code is buggy, but why GCC/clang and C/C++ does not have the same behavior?

Comment: @tadman Both `foo` and `foo2` have that bug. Why do they compile differently?

Comment: @Barmar It's inconsistent behaviour in the compiler. `return 0` makes both `xor` the same, but `void` functions have no `xor` at all.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: The C standard does not prohibit a function with non-void return type from flowing to the end of its closing brace. The code shown has behavior defined by the C standard, and the compiler is required to compile it to behavior specified by the standard.

Comment: It is interesting that, when the functions are swapped in the source code, the compiler puts the `XOR` in the second one, not the first. This is some GCC quirk, not something induced by the C standard.

Comment: @ikegami: There is no undefined behavior in the code shown. See my comment above about non-void functions being allowed to terminate by flowing to their closing braces.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah, just saw. Deleted comment answer. Do you know where that is in the spc?

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK. Although if the caller uses the value, there's UB. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12

Comment: @ikegami: There is nothing that explicitly says a non-void function can flow to its closing `}`; that is just part of the overall specification of the language. You can take it as part of C 2018 6.9 11: “After all parameters have been assigned, the compound statement that constitutes the body of the function definition is executed.” C 2018 6.9.1 12 indicates there is a problem specifically if the value of the function is used: “Unless otherwise specified, if the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @Barmar: Sure, but that is not relevant to this question. The `xor eax, eax` appears to be superfluous to the function, both because we see no need for it in the semantics specified by the C standard and because GCC omits it if the function is the first in the translation unit. So, if GCC keeps it in, that appears to be a failure of its optimization feature.

Comment: Interesting: changing to `-O1` gets rid of that instruction, but it appears in `-O2` and `-O3`. So it's a minor bug in the optimizer.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil thanks

Comment: Gcc is less comfortable with indeterminate values than clang and it sometimes annoyingly zeroes them (`xor %eax, %eax` <=> `int myreturn_value = 0;`). It especially tends to do this if the indeterminate is explicitly spelled out as in `int r; return r;`. Clang does nothing for this as it should. Gcc does `return 0;`. https://godbolt.org/z/zf4Y43Mqc

Comment: UB is UB. I would not fill the report as it is useless.

Comment: @0___________: There is no undefined behavior in the code shown. The C standard allows a non-void function to return by flowing to its closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a GCC optimizer bug. Reducing the optimization level to `-O1` generates the same code for both functions, without the `xor` instruction.

And if you look at the color coding in Godbolt, it's unable to associate the statements in the second funcction with assembly code lines. It just colors the function header line with the entire body in the generated code.

That instruction sets the return value of the function. Since the function doesn't have a `return` statement, it can return any value (according to [Section 6.9.12(12)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12) it's undefined behavior to use the returned value); `foo` returns whatever happens to be in `eax`, while `foo2` will always return `0`. So the bug doesn't have any impact on the correctness of the generated code. It's weird that it's inconsistent, but not a violation of the standard.

Comment: Yes it does not have any behavior impact but a performance impact since it adds a useless instruction. Should I open a ticket to the gcc bug tracker?

Comment: @poypoy: Sure, report it.